# I want to read from a txt file and write to an existing JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have created a JFrame with a JTable inside and I am able to write info on the cells. I can click the Save JMenuItem Save and the info is written into a txt file.
However, when I try to read the file and bring it back to the Table I face three problems.

1. The JTable consists of 30 rows. When the code reads the txt file, add rows underneath the 30th one. Is there a way to start filling the input from the first row instead of the 31st? -- SOLVED
2. The data is not written correctly. All of them are written in the first column -- SOLVED
3. How can I get rid of the "null" string? --SOLVED

My txt file format is like this:

```
Number;Type;IP;Protocol;Line;
49897223040;WE4;192.168.12.98;TCP;Single;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
null;null;null;null;null;
```

My Code is as follows:

```
public class PhoneOrganiser extends JFrame {
public static void main(String[] args){


            //creation of the Window
            JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Phone Organiser");
            frame.setSize(200, 300);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);

            //declaring the type of Table, Number of columns and rows
            String col[] ={"Number", "Type", "IP", "Protocol", "Line"};
            DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel (col,30);

            //create the table
            JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);

            //add the Table to the scrollpane 
            JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
            frame.add(scrollpane);

            //creating the Menu bar
            JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
            frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);

            //adding menus
            JMenu file = new JMenu ("File");
            menubar.add(file);


            JMenu help = new JMenu ("Help");
            menubar.add(help);


            //adding items inside the menus
            JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem ("Open");
            file.add(open);

            JMenuItem save = new JMenuItem ("Save");
            file.add(save);



            JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem ("Exit");
            file.add(exit);
            exit.addActionListener(new Exit());

            JMenuItem readMe = new JMenuItem ("Read me file");
            help.add(readMe);
            readMe.addActionListener(new ReadMe());
            JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem ("About");
            help.add(about);
            about.addActionListener(new About());





    //When the program starts for the first time, it creates a new txt file
    Path path = Paths.get("/Users/PhoneData.txt");
    try{
        Files.createFile(path);
        System.out.println("file created");
    }catch (IOException e1){
        System.out.println("file already exists");
    }


    //saving data from TABLE -> TO TXT - It can be done with FileChooser in V2

    class SaveData extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

            try{

                File file = new File ("C:\\Users\\PhoneData.txt"); //declaring the path of the file
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter (file.getAbsoluteFile()); 
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (fw);

                    //rows
                    for (int i =0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++){

                        //columns
                        for (int j=0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++){
                            bw.write((String)table.getModel().getValueAt(i, j)+ ";"); //write the contents to the file

                        }
                        bw.write("/");
                        bw.newLine();
                    }
                    bw.close();
                    fw.close();

            }catch (IOException e2){

            }//end catch

        }//end action method


    }save.addActionListener(new SaveData()); //end SaveData class


    //reading data from TXT -> TO TABLE

    class OpenData extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

            String line = null;

            try{

                File file = new File ("C:\\Users\\PhoneData.txt");
                FileReader fr = new FileReader (file.getAbsoluteFile());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr);

                while((line = br.readLine()) != "null;") 
                {

                    String [] splitData = line.split("/");
                    Values values = new Values();
                    values.setNumber(splitData[0]);
                    //values.setType(splitData[1]);
                    //values.setIP(splitData[2]);
                    //values.setProtocol(splitData[3]);
                    //values.setLine(splitData[4]);
                    tableModel.addRow(line.split("")); 
                }
                br.close();

            }catch (IOException e3){


            }//end catch

        }//end action method

    }open.addActionListener(new OpenData());//end OpenData class






}//end main
}//end class


public  class Values{
        private String Number;
        private String Type;
        private String IP;
        private String Protocol;
        private String Line;

        public String getNumber(){
            return Number;
        }
        public void setNumber(String Number){
            this.Number = Number;
        }


        public String getType(){
            return Type;
        }
        public void setType(String Type){
            this.Type = Type;
        }


        public String getIP(){
            return IP;
        }
        public void setIP(String IP){
            this.IP = IP;
        }


        public String getProtocol(){
            return Protocol;
        }
        public void setProtocol(String Protocol){
            this.Protocol = Protocol;
        }


        public String getLine(){
            return Line;
        }
        public void setLine(String Line){
            this.Line = Line;
        }
    }//end class Values
```

Comment: can you format the code?

Comment: Is it not correct? What should I do?

Comment: Look at the new part for the text file

Comment: aa OK. Thank you. Will do that next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad.3
Code is pretty much clear:

```
 for (int j=0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++){
      String value = (String)table.getModel().getValueAt(i, j);
      if((value == null || "null".equals(value)){
          value = "";
      }
      bw.write(value+";"); //write the contents to the file
 }
```

Ad.2
Need simple modification in your code:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(line);
    }
String[] lineArray= builder.toString().split("/");
for(String line: lineArray){
    String[] dataArray = line.split(";");
    tableModel.addRow(dataArray);
}
```

Ad.1 
Hope this is something that you want to achive. Full code below:

```
public class PhoneOrganiser extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args){


    //creation of the Window
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Phone Organiser");
    frame.setSize(200, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    //declaring the type of Table, Number of columns and rows
    final String col[] ={"Number", "Type", "IP", "Protocol", "Line"};
    final DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel (col,30);

    //create the table
    final JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);

    //add the Table to the scrollpane
    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
    frame.add(scrollpane);

    //creating the Menu bar
    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);

    //adding menus
    JMenu file = new JMenu ("File");
    menubar.add(file);

    JMenu help = new JMenu ("Help");
    menubar.add(help);

    //adding items inside the menus
    JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem ("Open");
    file.add(open);

    JMenuItem save = new JMenuItem ("Save");
    file.add(save);


    JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem ("Exit");
    file.add(exit);


    //When the program starts for the first time, it creates a new txt file
    Path path = Paths.get("/Users/PhoneData.txt");
    try{
        Files.createFile(path);
        System.out.println("file created");
    }catch (IOException e1){
        System.out.println("file already exists");
    }

    //saving data from TABLE -> TO TXT - It can be done with FileChooser in V2

    class SaveData extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

            try{

                File file = new File ("C:\\Inne\\PhoneData.txt"); //declaring the path of the file
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter (file.getAbsoluteFile());
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (fw);

                //rows
                for (int i =0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++){

                    for (int j=0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++){
                        String value = (String)table.getModel().getValueAt(i, j);
                        if((value == null || "null".equals(value))) {
                            value = "";
                        }
                        bw.write(value+";"); //write the contents to the file
                    }
                    bw.write("/");
                    bw.newLine();
                }
                bw.close();
                fw.close();

            }catch (IOException e2){

            }//end catch

        }//end action method


    }
    save.addActionListener(new SaveData()); //end SaveData class

    //reading data from TXT -> TO TABLE

    class OpenData extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

            String line = null;
            try{

                File file = new File ("C:\\Inne\\PhoneData.txt");
                FileReader fr = new FileReader (file.getAbsoluteFile());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr);

                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
                String[] lineArray= builder.toString().split("/");
                table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(col,0));
                for(String currentLine: lineArray){
                    String[] dataArray = currentLine.split(";");
                    ((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).addRow(dataArray);
                }
                br.close();

            }catch (IOException e3){


            }//end catch

        }//end action method

    }open.addActionListener(new OpenData());//end OpenData class

}
}
```

Comment: The concept is this:
I have a JTable and the user is able to complete some info.
He selects File -> Save and the contents of the table are written into a txt file. If the user closes the program and reopens it, I want him to be able to select File -> Open and the contents that were previously written in the txt file, to be loaded into the relevant fields in the JTable

Comment: Thanks a lot Pawel. Your answer helped a lot.
However one major problem still exist.
My JTable has a total of 30 rows. When the data is entered from the txt file, the code adds more rows underneath the 30th one. Is there a way to add the data starting on the first row onwards?

Comment: @Gabri,  `Is there a way to add the data starting on the first row onwards? –  Gabri 9 mins ago ` - clear the data in the TableModel before you add the rows to the model: `tableModel.setRowCount(0)`.

Comment: Just updated answer. Please mark as answered if it something that you want to achive. I just changed there only paths to files. Take a look.

Comment: (1+) @PawełGłowacz, it is better to clear the table model as I suggested in my comment above, instead of creating a new empty TableModel. When you create a new TableModel the TableColumnModel will also be recreated and any custom renderer or editor added to the table could be lost. Agreed there are no custom renderers or editors in this example it is just a good idea to follow this approach so you don't need to worry about this.

Comment: @Gabri, don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark, so people know the problem has been solved.