# Dynamic search filter in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter, documentlistener

This question is related to the one mentioned here:
[[I want to read from a txt file and write to an existing JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318587/i-want-to-read-from-a-txt-file-and-write-to-an-existing-jtable][1])

I have made a program which can read from a txt file and write onto a JTable. I have also created a method which allows me to dynamically searching the contents of the JTable and display the results that match the word.
However, every new entry that I am writing at the JTable is able to be found from the filter. BUT when I load a txt file contents and try to use the search filter afterwards, the results cannot be displayed the the JTable disappears as soon as I start typing something on the text field.

My code for the search method is as follows:

```
//Creation and functionality of the Search Field

class TestTableSortFilter extends JPanel {
    public TableRowSorter < TableModel > rowSorter = new TableRowSorter < > (table.getModel());
    public JTextField searchFilter = new JTextField();
    public TestTableSortFilter() {
        table.setRowSorter(rowSorter);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(new JLabel("Search:"),
        BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel.add(searchFilter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        searchFilter.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                String text = searchFilter.getText();
                if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
                } else {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                String text = searchFilter.getText();
                if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
                } else {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
            }
        });
    } //end TestTableSortFilter
  } //end class table sort & creating the sorter for Search
```

Comment: `throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");` ... isn't going to help...

Comment: If I remove it I cannot use the DocumentListener anymore because it has to use the DocumentEvent update

Comment: You need to remove the `Exception`, otherwise it will cause the `DocumentListener` to stop responding and make the EDT unstable

Comment: I did that but the problem unfortunately persists. When I open the database and the program reads the Strings from the txt file, it is not able to perform any search

Comment: I guess from the look of your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318587/i-want-to-read-from-a-txt-file-and-write-to-an-existing-jtable), you would need to use [TableRowSorter#setModel(newModel)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html#setModel-M-) after using `JTable#setModel(newModel)` method.

Comment: FYI: the `JXTable` from the SwingX project has search support build-in using the `JXSearchField` and `JXSearchPanel`

Comment: on which class? The OpenData where I read from the txt file?
there is the `table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(col,0));` line there. Is it the one that should be changed?

Comment: @Robin: Unfortunately I cannot change my project to SwingX now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> on which class? The OpenData where I read from the txt file? there is the table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(col,0)); line there. Is it the one that should be changed?

Try something like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class RowSorterTest {
  private final String[] columnNames = {"Number", "Type", "IP", "Protocol", "Line"};
  private final Object[][] data = {
    {"aaa", "1", "", "", ""}, {"bbbbb", "", "", "", ""}
  };
  private final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
    @Override public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
      return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
    }
  };
  private final JTable table = new JTable(model);
  private final TableRowSorter<TableModel> rowSorter = new TableRowSorter<>(model);
  private final JTextField searchFilter = new JTextField();
  private final JButton open = new JButton("open");

  public JComponent makeUI() {
    table.setRowSorter(rowSorter);
    open.addActionListener(new OpenData());//end OpenData class

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(new JLabel("Search:"), BorderLayout.WEST);
    panel.add(searchFilter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(open, BorderLayout.EAST);

    searchFilter.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
      @Override
      public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        String text = searchFilter.getText();
        System.out.println(text);
        if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
          rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
        } else {
          rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
        }
        table.repaint();
      }
      @Override
      public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        String text = searchFilter.getText();
        if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
          rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
        } else {
          rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
        }
      }
      @Override
      public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        //not needed: throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
      }
    });

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(new JScrollPane(table));
    p.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    return p;
  }
  class OpenData implements ActionListener {
    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//       String line = null;
//       try{
//           File file = new File ("C:\\Inne\\PhoneData.txt");
//           FileReader fr = new FileReader (file.getAbsoluteFile());
//           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr);
//           StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
//           while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
//               builder.append(line);
//           }
//           String[] lineArray= builder.toString().split("/");
//           table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0));
//           for(String currentLine: lineArray){
//               String[] dataArray = currentLine.split(";");
//               ((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).addRow(dataArray);
//           }
//           br.close();
//       }catch (IOException e3) {
//           e3.printStackTrace();
//       }//end catch
      DefaultTableModel m = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
      //Dummy data
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        String[] dataArray = {"aa" + i, "", "", "", ""};
        m.addRow(dataArray);
      }
      table.setModel(m);
      rowSorter.setModel(m);
    }//end action method
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new RowSorterTest().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For the specific example that you mention the code works, but the code regarding the reading of the txt file is commented out. I tried to incorporate it in my code but as soon as I hit Open the table disappears again. For some reason I have to add the `FileReader` and the `BufferedReader` in my code. And when I run this the problem is on the `((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).addRow(dataArray);` line

Comment: I made it to work...discard my last comment.
Thanks a lot aterai!

Comment: +1 For the regex filter parameters. Quick note: `"^(?i)" + text` will search the start of the text string, which took me a little while to figure out so I thought I'd point it out just in case someone is looking for it.